# Exclude localhost from htt_proxy

Tags: proxy, http, localhost

I'm trying to access a server that is running locally on my machine (localhost). I'm using the "wget"-command to download the servers http-response. I've also tried using the "curl"-command to do this, but both (wget and curl) are trying to get through my proxy-server and failing at it:

```
--2010-05-04 09:05:34--  http://localhost:8080/api/getplist
...
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 503 Service Unavailable
2010-05-04 09:05:35 ERROR 503: Service Unavailable.
```

Obviously they shouldn't need to go through the proxy, right? So I disabled the http_proxy:

```
export http_proxy=""
```

And then it worked fine. Disabling the the http_proxy every time or permanently are no options. How can I set it to ignore the proxy settings when accessing "localhost"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the environment variable `NO_PROXY` to include `localhost`.  It looks like curl expects this to be in upper case (`NO_PROXY`) and wget in lower case (`no_proxy`).

For wget you can also set the `no_proxy` list in the `.wgetrc` file (see `info wget`).

Comment: Setting the no_proxy variable worked! Thanks.